# Does unpacking sequences [strings, lists] and sets involve casting into a tuple?

Tags: python, argument-unpacking

I just learnt of unpacking with the `*` and so went on some test runs. I realized that although some write about passing in tuples as arguments in place of positional arguments, I could also pass in strings, lists and sets and Python wouldn't complain as long as I included the `*`. I have listed below what I defined as a function taking in positional arguments and the test cases.

What surprised me are the `Traceback`s, which led to my question. The `Traceback`s mention an `IndexError` for a tuple even when none is provided. Is what is happening under the hood a casting of the lists, strings and sets into tuples when the `*` is used?

```
>>> def print2nd(*args):
...     print(args[1])

>>> s = "abc"
>>> print2nd(*s)
b
>>> print2nd(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in print2nd
IndexError: tuple index out of range

>>> t = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print2nd(*t)
b
>>> u = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> print2nd(*u)
a
>>> print2nd(u)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in print2nd
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> u[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
>>> tuple(u)
('b', 'a', 'c')
>>> tuple(u)[1]
'a'
```

Comment: Seems so, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365795/9209546).

Comment: @jpp, thanks. Would you care to write an answer or should I close the question?

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate for now, since it could be a good marker for others who have the same question.

Comment: @jpp, could that not lead to downvoting the question?

Comment: I hope not, I actually think it's a useful question (even though an answer on a similar question is sufficient) with different keywords. So it deserves upvoting, in my opinion.

Comment: @heretoinfinity The single argument you pass in to the function is *not converted* to a tuple but instead *wrapped* by a tuple. That wrapper tuple has as many elements as arguments passed to the function. Since you passed only one argument and `args[1]` attempts to access the second argument there's an `IndexError`. On the other hand `func(*s)` means pass every element of `s` as an argument to `func`. Hence `args` contains the same elements as `s`.

Comment: @a_guest, could you clarify the meaning of a wrapper tuple? I am not well versed with wrappers.

Comment: @heretoinfinity It's nothing special, I just used that term to reference the "wrapped by a tuple" part. So it's just an ordinary tuple that's being created and all the arguments are stuffed into it.